# Android Studio Startup Error (32 bit)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

I'm Facing problem with latest version of android studio(1.0).
Andorid Studio is install correctly in my PC but when I try to start its show error window with following error code.

What I have done:

1. Set JDK path JAVA_HOME
2. SDK path to android studio

**My ERROR is:**

> ```
> Internal error. Please report to
> http://code.google.com/p/android/issues
>
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
> javax.crypto.Cipher.getMaxAllowedKeyLength(Ljava/lang/String;)I
>     at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite$BulkCipher.isAvailable(CipherSuite.java:548)
>     at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite$BulkCipher.isAvailable(CipherSuite.java:527)
>     at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite.isAvailable(CipherSuite.java:194)
>     at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl.getApplicableCipherSuiteList(SSLContextImpl.java:350)
>     at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl.getDefaultCipherSuiteList(SSLContextImpl.java:308)
>     at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.init(SSLSocketImpl.java:607)
>     at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.<init>(SSLSocketImpl.java:519)
>     at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(SSLSocketFactoryImpl.java:72)
>     at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:503)
>     at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:377)
>     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:165)
>     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:304)
>     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:610)
>     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:445)
>     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
>     at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
>     at com.android.sdklib.internal.repository.UrlOpener.openWithHttpClient(UrlOpener.java:404)
>     at com.android.sdklib.internal.repository.UrlOpener.openUrl(UrlOpener.java:183)
>     at com.android.sdklib.internal.repository.DownloadCache.openUrl(DownloadCache.java:293)
>     at com.android.sdklib.internal.repository.DownloadCache.downloadAndCache(DownloadCache.java:676)
>     at com.android.sdklib.internal.repository.DownloadCache.openCachedUrl(DownloadCache.java:509)
>     at com.android.sdklib.internal.repository.AddonsListFetcher.fetchXmlUrl(AddonsListFetcher.java:267)
>     at com.android.sdklib.internal.repository.AddonsListFetcher.fetch(AddonsListFetcher.java:132)
>     at com.android.sdklib.repository.remote.RemoteSdk.fetchSources(RemoteSdk.java:191)
>     at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.AndroidStudioWelcomeScreenProvider.fetchPackages(AndroidStudioWelcomeScreenProvider.java:107)
>     at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.AndroidStudioWelcomeScreenProvider.access$000(AndroidStudioWelcomeScreenProvider.java:41)
>     at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.AndroidStudioWelcomeScreenProvider$1.compute(AndroidStudioWelcomeScreenProvider.java:91)
>     at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.AndroidStudioWelcomeScreenProvider$1.compute(AndroidStudioWelcomeScreenProvider.java:88)
>     at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$4.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:240)
>     at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$TaskRunnable.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:471)
>     at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$6.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:281)
>     at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:178)
>     at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManager.java:209)
>     at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:212)
>     at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:171)
>     at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$10$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:645)
>     at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:419)
>     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
>     at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:149)
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using latest version of JDK.